# Не работает метод submit

Tags: jquery, javascript, html

Хочу отменить отправку формы обработчику, пока не будут заполнены все поля. В инпуте пустота, но все равно submit срабатывает.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

 $('#send').submit(function(eventObject){

     if($('#name').val() == "" || $('#email').val()=='' || $('#date').val()=='') { 
          eventObject.preventDefault(); alert('Вы заполнили не все поля');}
     });
 </script>
```

Как я заметил, программа вообще во внутрь функции   не заходит

Comment: jQuery точно подключён?
У кнопки отправки формы id send?

Comment: <input name = "send" type="submit" value="Перейти к выбору времени" id="send" class="btn-send" />

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Цитата из [официального руководства](http://api.jquery.com/submit/)

> The submit event is sent to an element
> when the user is attempting to submit
> a form. It can only be attached to `<form>` elements.

Надо вешать этот обработчик к форме, а вы похоже к submit-кнопке его вешаете.

Comment: Кнопка отправляет же форму. 
А как по другому к форме можно вешать?

Comment: Например задайте своей форме id

    <form id="mysuperform">
    ...
    </form>
    <script type="text/javascript">
     $('#mysuperform').submit(function(eventObject){
       ....
     });
    </script>

Comment: Работает только тогда, когда  форме уже переданы параметры. В моем случаем методом ГЕТ. А в первый раз не выполняется. Как это можно исправить?

      <form action="appointments.php" method="get" class="reservationForm" id="reservationForm">